# Perl script to capture the stderr messages without using use Capture::Tiny module

Tags: perl

I had an issue in capturing the stderr messages using the backticks command say 'make target' in perl. Hence I had used the module  Capture::Tiny to capture the stderr messages. But I am issues in installing it and want to know alternative ways other than using this module.

Please let me know if you know any.

Regards,
Poornima

Comment: redirecting STDERR `make target 2>/tmp/stderr` might be one way

Answer (score 0):

From [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> Because backticks do not affect standard error, use shell file
>   descriptor syntax (assuming the shell supports this) if you care to
>   address this. To capture a command's STDERR and STDOUT together:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>&1`;
> ```
>
> To capture a command's STDOUT but discard its STDERR:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>/dev/null`;
> ```
>
> To capture a command's STDERR but discard its STDOUT (ordering is important here):
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
> ```
>
> To exchange a command's STDOUT and STDERR in order to capture the STDERR but leave its STDOUT to come
>   out the old STDERR:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`;
> ```
>
> To read both a command's STDOUT and its STDERR separately, it's easiest to redirect them
>   separately to files, and then read from those files when the program
>   is done:
>
> ```
> system("program args 1>program.stdout 2>program.stderr");
> ```